# Is the sum a formal power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Given a series

$$\sum_{i \ge 0} x^{a\cdot i}(x^{b\cdot i} - 1)$$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$

Would this series be considered a formal power series?

Comment: Rather the difference of two power series.

Comment: @Did, so it must a power series then?

Comment: You probably want to assume $a>0$ and $b>0$.

Comment: It may depend on how you define this expression. But if you identify this as the 'limit' of the sequence of polynomials $\sum_{i=0}^{n} x^{ai}(x^{bi}-1)$ as $n\to\infty$, then yes, it converges in the ring of formal power series and the limit is the same as $\sum_{i\geq 0} x^{(a+b)i} - \sum_{i\geq 0} x^{ai}$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by the question.

If you're referring to the formula itself, it is not in the form of a formal power series. Nor is it in any of the other closely related forms that we don't bother distinguishing from the correct form.

However, if you mean the *value* of the formula as it would be calculated in formal power series about $x=0$, then if $a > 0$ or $b=0$, the formula *does* have a value that is a formal power series.

---

To clarify what I mean about "closely related forms", technically speaking,

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} x^{2i} $$

is not in the form of a power series. However, when we want to talk about things the form of a power series, we conventionally interpret such a formula as if it were instead the formula

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n} $$

where the sequence of coefficients $a_n$ is given by

$$ a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & n \text{ even} 
\\ 0 & n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}$$